# TERM environment variable not set

Tags: macos

Empece a hacer mi programa en **dev c sin** y no tenia ningún error.

Luego quise continuar en **codeblocks** desde mac pero en la terminal me aparecía esto:

> TERM environment variable not set

Aparecía en cada ventana como titulo y como me estaba dando problemas, creí que era codeblocks.

Decidí programar en **Xcode** aunque no tengo tanta experiencia, pero eso seguía apareciendo en la terminal. ¿Que puede ser?

Comment: Entiendo que cuando estabas programando con dev estabas en Windows y luego pasastes a mac, ¿cierto?

Comment: Así es. Como no hay dev c para mac. Estaba utilizando code blocs

Answer (score 0):

TERM es una variable de entorno utilizada para configurar, al menos que yo sepa, una terminal `cron`.

Se ve que el proyecto de MAC intenta crear una consola de esta manera y al no estar definida la variable en tu sistema te encuentras con el error.

Prueba a configurar el proyecto para que haga uso de dicha variable de entorno o dala de alta en el sistema directamente.

Tendrías que hacer algo similar a esto:

```
export TERM=xterm
```